# how can i create a countdown timer using a datepicker selector?

Tags: datepicker, countdowntimer

i have a question for you. i'm trying to create a countdown timer in Xcode 5 using the datepicker in "count down timer" mode. i tried several times but it still doesn't work. probably i miss something in my code. can you help me? thanks!!

Comment: Could you include the code you've got so far but failed to work?

Comment: #import  "ViewController.h"
@ interface ViewController  ( )
@ end
@ implementation ViewController
-(IBAction) Start {
mainInt = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;
timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTImeInterval:1  target:self  selector:@ "selector"(CountDown) userInfo:nil  rewpeats:YES];
}
-(void) countDown {
mainInt -= 1;
hours.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ "%i",mainInt]
second.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ "%i",mainInt]
if  (mainInt ==0)  {
[timer invalidate]
}

}

Comment: i know is wrong, please forgive me.. i started coding two weeks ago :(     

thanks for helping @EWit